# How to write a procedural macro that implements a generic trait, fx. Add?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a `Module` trait and I would like to write a procedural macro that implements `Add`, `Sub`, and `Mul` for any implementation of the `Module` trait.

Given a struct `Foo<S>` that implements `Module`, the resulting code should look like this

```rust
impl <S, RHS: Module>  std::ops::Add<RHS> for Foo<S> {
    type Output = crate::modules::Add<Foo<S>, RHS>;

    fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output {
        crate::modules::Add::new(self, rhs)
    }
}
```

The problem is that both the struct and the `Add` trait have their own generic types.
If this weren't the case, the macro code could look something like this

```rust
let name = &ast.ident;
let generics = &ast.generics;
let (impl_generics, ty_generics, where_clause) = generics.split_for_impl();
quote! {
    impl #impl_generics std::ops::Add<RHS> for #name #ty_generics #where_clause {
        type Output = crate::modules::Add<#name, RHS>;
        
        fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output {
            crate::modules::Add::new(self, rhs)
        }
    }
}
```

but then the `RHS` type is never defined.
I have tried variations on `<#impl_generics, RHS: Module>` and the like, but none of them work.

Obviously a blanket implementation of `Add` for `T: Module` would be better, but this is impossible to do because foreign traits can't be implemented for type parameters. See [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0210). A workaround for this would also solve my problem in this specific case, but it seems like what I'm asking about should be possible.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to handle the type parameters for Foo manually instead of using `generics.split_for_impl()`.
A working version of my example above becomes.

```rust
let name = &ast.ident;
let generics = &ast.generics;
let type_params = generics.type_params();
let (_, ty_generics, where_clause) = generics.split_for_impl();
quote! {
    #ast // This is not a derive macro, sp this is necessary to keep the original struct definition.
    impl <#(#type_params),*, RHS: crate::modules::Module>  std::ops::Add<RHS> for #name #ty_generics #where_clause {
        type Output = crate::modules::Add<#name #ty_generics, RHS>;

        fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output {
            crate::modules::Add::new(self, rhs)
        }
    }
}
```

Where `type_params` is an iterator of the type parameters with bounds and the `#(#type_params),*,` creates a list of these type parameters.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `#(#type_params,)*` instead of `#(#type_params),*,`? Something like: `impl<#(#lifetimes,)* #(#type_params,)* 'a, T> MyTrait<'a, T> for...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your macro code is not working, but an easier way would be to write a blanket impl for any `T` that implements `Module`, and avoid macros entirely:

```rust
impl<T, Rhs> std::ops::Add<Rhs> for T
where
    T: Module,
    Rhs: Module,
{
    type Output = crate::modules::Add<T, Rhs>;

    fn add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output {
        crate::modules::Add::new(self, rhs)
    }
}
```

Comment: This would definitely be the better solution, but I can't blanket impl `Add` for `Module`, without the specialization feature of Rust. The problem comes from the possibility of Add later being implemented for a struct also implementing Module, then there are two implementations. A workaround for _that_ would also be a solution for my problem.

Comment: Just realized that a blanket impl is actually impossible because of this error: https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0210